# accessing source code from a local file python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, local, inspect

I need to access the source code of a locally saved file, but I need to automate this because there are multiple files in one folder. I've looked at the inspect module and the selenium module, but I still understand what to do. After accessing the source code, I need to use bs4 to extract from it.

I've read several posts on here and elsewhere with similar problems, but the thing is that my file does not open in the source code (it's written in xml and so far everything needs to be in source code before you can use these modules). If I open the file, it just uses my browser to open a regular page and then I have to click view page source.

How can I automate this so that it will open the page, go to the source code, and save it so I can stick it into a soup for later parsing?

```
path_g_jurt = r'C:\Users\g\Desktop\t\SDU\jurt htmls\jurt\meta jurt'

file = r'C:\Users\g\Desktop\t\SDU\jurt htmls\jurt\meta jurt' + "/" + file

for file in path_g_jurt:
if file.endswith(".xhtml"):
with open(file, encoding = "utf-8") as mdata_jurt:

soup = BeautifulSoup(mdata_jurt)
main = file.find("jcid").get_text()
misc_links = []
for item in file.find_all("regelgeving"):
    misc = item.find("misc:link")
    misc_links.append(misc.get("misc:jcid"))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What specifically is in the file that you need to access?

Comment: `for file in path_g_jurt` will iterate over each caracter of the string, not the directory contents. Try [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), or the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module to list the contents

Comment: @Harrison it's an xhtml containing legal data. so it's something law1.xhtml, law2.xhtml etc all saved locally on one file because the company had online access issues.

Comment: @mata sorry i have absolutely no idea how/what to implement os.listdir(). i understand what you mean that it's iterating incorrectly but i have two data sets and one opens in a perfect xml source code but the other is the bane of my existence. the first dataset works perfectly with this code meaning it can extract the relevant info because it can iterate over the xml. the second nightmarish one first opens as a scrambled text but the source code is also in xml. i just need to automate opening that file (from dataset 2) as it's source code.

Comment: working code for dataset 1 (non-nightmarish one):

Comment: @mata sorry! i went back to double check and i must retyped something wrong because original code already uses it so this is not the problem